# Post TypeScript Compilation: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, syntax-error

> Scenario

Whenever I run my application from `index.html`, referencing the `main.js` file, which has been compiled from Typescript using `es6` as the target and `ESNext` as the module, I get this error within the browser:

> Error

`main.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

> Main.ts

```
    ///     IMPORTS
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    import { Player }     from './classes/Player'   <= Error Here!
    import { printTable } from './helpers/Helpers'

    ///     MAIN COMMANDS
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    let p1 = new Player('Bob', 'Hunter', 1, 10);

    printTable(p1);
```

> Concept

I appear to be importing my code improperly, and (for whatever reason) don't know why or can't figure it out. Everywhere I look, this is indicated as the method of importing exported code, classes, etc... When all code exists within a single file, all classes, interfaces, helpers, etc..., everything converts and runs dandy, except when I want to compartmentalize my code, and handle it this way.

Any guidance would surely be appreciate.

- Cheers and thanks in advance!

> [Source Code](https://bitbucket.org/justinbyrne001/player/src/master/)

Comment: Is Player the default export from `'./classes/Player'`? If so, you need `import Player from './classes/Player'`, otherwise it's trying to find a named export and since one doesn't exist failing.

Comment: Checkout this article to learn more about named vs default exports https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...and ESNext as the module, I get this error within the browser:
>   `main.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Your error here is that you are trying to use ES6 import syntax in a traditional script (`<script src="index.js"></script>`). Using ES6 `import` and `export` only works with modules, used in the browser with `<script type="module" src="whatever"></script>`.

Have you looked into using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)? It can automatically compile your TypeScript files into one JavaScript bundle that you can load into your HTML file with a single script tag.

Comment: Quick question: is this what I'm essentially doing!? Would Webpack be the solution for the methodology that I'm using, or could TypeScript (itself) potentially be written in a manner that could output the desired result?

Comment: I think Webpack would be the solution for the methodology that you're using. TypeScript itself just compiles to individual JavaScript files, all of which you would have to include in your HTML with `<script type="module"></script>`, and that gets hard to manage with dozens of files. Unless you want to write your entire application in a few .ts files, I would recommend bundling them.

Answer (score 0):

For you to import in this way you are using, you must export the class reference directly, without being inside an object.

Examples:

(correct) export Player;
(wrong) export { Player }

Comment: This would not be a SyntaxError, if this were the problem the error message would say something like "could not find Player".